# Convert RTSP stream to HTTP and stream it with VLC client

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I have an IP-camera which deliveser a stream by RTSP, i can play it on PC with VLC player using the following URL:

```
rtsp://192.168.1.52:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?
```

I have linux server, and i want  convert RTSP to HTTP and transmit it. I tryed like this, but it does not work:

```
vlc -vvv 'rtsp://192.168.1.52:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?' --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ogg,url=192.168.1.41:8081}'
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What codec does your camera deliver? I guess h264. 
Have you tried reencoding the stream into a format which is compatible with the ogg container? 
For Ogg you would probably go for video/theora and audio/vorbis. 
Use #transcode{} do deal with reencoding your stream. 
Also, what does your VLC log say?